# Communicate between isolated worlds (extension js and webpage js) on chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

As you may know, js files on chrome extensions and pages cannot directly access each other and they run on isolated worlds.

However, I want to access some of the functions on a page and call those functions from the plugin.

And I do not want to make my own version of those functions.

I'm wondering if this is possible... Would appreciate all the answers.

**EDIT**: The functions are on the background page. Its a browser action extension.

*more info:* Basically, I have a context menu which creates a tab to submit url to a page. however, re-opening the page makes many tabs and opening so many pages takes time. So I am willing to call the javascript function on the page directly from the extension if one instance of the page is open already. And I have access to the page permission-wise.

**TL;DR**: Need a way to call a javascript function on a page (without copying it locally) from an extension.

Comment: Can you be more specific about where the functions are? Background_pages, content_scripts, browser_action popups?

Comment: Its from a background page with a browser_action extension type. updated the question with specifics.

Comment: Is the page with the function you need to run an extension page or a page on the web? If it is a page on the web can you modify the code or do you have no control over what is returned from the servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you know the tab ID of the page whose function you want to call, you can use `chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {url: 'javascript:functionNameHere()'});` from your extension page. This works because javascript: URLs are [mapped](http://www.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/browser/extensions/extension_tabs_module.cc&q=in_main_world%20executescript%20file%3aExtension&exact_package=chromium&type=cs&l=1061) to script execution in the main (i.e. page, not isolated) world.

Comment: Perfect answer. Even though being an experienced developer I completely forgot about running inline JS. Thanks Mihai :)